# How to apply rounded corners for button programmatically added to a StackView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm having an issue with adding top right and left rounded button, to a stackview. Buttons added via interface builder, and then rounded by the extension, will render, but not if the button is added via code. Possibly there is some additional attribute that IB applies.

Here is an extract of the code, which illustrates the problem.

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
let colorDictionary = ["Red":UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0),"Green":UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0),"Blue":UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0),]

func colorButton(withColor color:UIColor, title:String) -> UIButton{
    let newButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    newButton.backgroundColor = color
    newButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    newButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)

    //Buttons fail to render if roundedButton() is applied
    //**************************
    //newButton.roundedButton()
    //**************************
    return newButton
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    displayButtonsInStackView()
}

func displayButtonsInStackView(){
    //generate an array

    var buttonArray = [UIButton]()
    for (myKey,myValue) in colorDictionary{
        buttonArray += [colorButton(withColor: myValue, title: myKey)]
    }

     let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttonArray)
     stackView.axis = .horizontal
     stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
     stackView.alignment = .fill
     stackView.spacing = 5
     stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     view.addSubview(stackView)

    //autolayout the stack view - pin 30 up 20 left 20 right 30 down
    let viewsDictionary = ["stackView":stackView]
    let stackView_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[stackView]-20-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    let stackView_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-30-[stackView]-30-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    view.addConstraints(stackView_H)
    view.addConstraints(stackView_V)
    }
}

extension UIButton {

    func roundedButton(){
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight , .topRight],
                                cornerRadii:CGSize(width:8.0, height:8.0))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing some critical code. (1) I can see where you are creating an array of  *colorButtons*, but where's the connection to *roundedButton()*? (2) If you simply populated your array with simple UIButtons, does it work like expected? (3) Can you provide a sample for *colorDictionary*? It will help duplicate the issue. (4) When you have "rounded buttons", what is rendered? From what you wrote, I think nothing. But please verify. Thanks.

Comment: 1. See 'newButton.roundedButton()' . 2. Simple butttons via an array does not work. 3. The code is listed in full. 4. Correct, nothing - the issue was the button had no size. IB obviously sets that by default.

Comment: And, it is worth adding, nothing whatever to do with the stack view. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your buttons have no size. Change this:

```
// ...
newButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
newButton.roundedButton()
// ...
```

to this:

```
// ...
newButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
newButton.sizeToFit()
newButton.roundedButton()
// ...
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks al lot!